# nuxt.js axios calls return "loading" html without hitting backend

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js

I have an existing app I've been developing for a few months, but I just changed to a new laptop. The specific issue is:

All of my axios calls immediately respond with a "loading" html before they can even reach the endpoint.

I have done separate testing to confirm that the endpoints are all working, that no errors are being thrown in the nuxt code, etc.

The requests all return immediately with a green 200, but the response is html for the loading as I mentioned. I have no idea how to even begin debugging this, and really haven't found any similar problem from my searching
we have:

```
axios: {
    progress: false,
},
```

in the config, is the only setting I can see that even relates

The response code is here (it is just a spinner in dev tools):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-n-head="%7B%22lang%22:%7B%221%22:%22en%22%7D%7D">

<head>
    <title>web</title>
    <meta data-n-head="1" charset="utf-8">
    <meta data-n-head="1" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta data-n-head="1" data-hid="description" name="description" content="">
    <link data-n-head="1" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/runtime.js" as="script">
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/commons/app.js" as="script">
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/vendors/app.js" as="script">
    <link rel="preload" href="/_nuxt/app.js" as="script">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="__nuxt">
        <style>
            #nuxt-loading {
                background: white;
                visibility: hidden;
                opacity: 0;
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                flex-direction: column;
                animation: nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;
                -webkit-animation: nuxtLoadingIn 10s ease;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            @keyframes nuxtLoadingIn {
                0% {
                    visibility: hidden;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                20% {
                    visibility: visible;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                100% {
                    visibility: visible;
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoadingIn {
                0% {
                    visibility: hidden;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                20% {
                    visibility: visible;
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                100% {
                    visibility: visible;
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }

            #nuxt-loading>div,
            #nuxt-loading>div:after {
                border-radius: 50%;
                width: 5rem;
                height: 5rem;
            }

            #nuxt-loading>div {
                font-size: 10px;
                position: relative;
                text-indent: -9999em;
                border: .5rem solid #F5F5F5;
                border-left: .5rem solid black;
                -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
                -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
                transform: translateZ(0);
                -webkit-animation: nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear;
                animation: nuxtLoading 1.1s infinite linear;
            }

            #nuxt-loading.error>div {
                border-left: .5rem solid #ff4500;
                animation-duration: 5s;
            }

            @-webkit-keyframes nuxtLoading {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
                }

                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
            }

            @keyframes nuxtLoading {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
                }

                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
            }
        </style>
        <script>window.addEventListener('error', function () { var e = document.getElementById('nuxt-loading'); if (e) { e.className += ' error'; } });</script>
        <div id="nuxt-loading" aria-live="polite" role="status">
            <div>Loading...</div>
        </div><!-- https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders -->
    </div>
    <script>window.__NUXT__ = { config: { _app: { basePath: "\u002F", assetsPath: "\u002F_nuxt\u002F", cdnURL: null } } }</script>
    <script src="/_nuxt/runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="/_nuxt/commons/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/_nuxt/vendors/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/_nuxt/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll post the answer in hopes that others will spend less time figuring this one out

There was a missing .env file for the front-end that gave the correct port to forward the requests to.

Because of this, axios was calling the front-end, not the back-end; it was completely "correctly", but obviously not what I wanted